# How to display scrolling index for scrollController in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to display the index at the bottom of the listView by utilizing the scrollController, the same way it's displayed in the follow image :

[image]

After the user scrolls down, or scrolls up, the count on the left, highlighted by red, gets increased/decreased based on the scroll direction of the user.

What I want to achieve is to automatically update the displayed item's index, indicated by red on the picture. So whenever the user scrolls down or up, this index gets updated by the displayed item's index.

The picture shows that I have reached the 26th item. Whenever I scroll down or up, this index gets updated.

I have tried using the offset that is getting emitted for the scrolling event with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way is using the scroll controller like you were doing.

You need to use a known item size and a listener.

```
// Declaring the controller and the item size
ScrollController _scrollController;
final itemSize = 100.0;

// Initializing
@override
void initState() {
  _scrollController = ScrollController();
  _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
  super.initState();
}

// Your list widget (must not be nested lists)
ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      itemCount: <Your list length>,
      itemExtent: itemSize,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(<your items>);
      },
),

// With the listener and the itemSize, you can calculate which item
// is on screen using the provided callBack. Something like this:
void _scrollListener() {
  setState(() {
    var index = (_scrollController.offset / itemSize).round() + 1;
  });
}
```

Adding a listener to a scrollController will call the callback provided every time the list is scrolled. You can handle many behaviours of the list using the same logic, including identifying the type of event that fired the listener, the direction of the scroll, etc.

Comment: Well I have used some different solution. I needed the equation to calculate the item size to increment the index.

One thing I found about your solution is that I don't know where _controller comes from, it would be more helpful if I knew its initialization.

Comment: Sorry, its all the same, controller is ScrollController. Im correcting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/flutter-community/create-shop-list-with-flutter-d13d3c20d68b
Maybe this one can help you. Also source code is available. A simple math about item height might help.