# Increase/decrease item count on scroll up/down in Listview builder whose items have variable size(height)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I am trying to display the item number in a separate widget. I am using Listview builder whose child(itemBuilder's return statement) is a card. The height of the card is not constant. It keeps changing depending on the length of the data, the card is displaying.

I found this => [How to display scrolling index for scrollController in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63511308/how-to-display-scrolling-index-for-scrollcontroller-in-flutter) . But in this solution, the card has a fixed size(height). Can somebody suggest what should be done if the card is of variable height.

Comment: the link is not working

Comment: Hey, thanks in advance. I have changed the link. Can you check it?  
@SaeedGhasemi